# FOSuserbundle login form & SamlBundle SSO login

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm working on a custom membership website which is based on the Symfony2. This website has two type of the bundles. FOSuserbundle and [SamlBundle](https://github.com/pdias/SamlBundle).

I integrated SamlBundle with FOSuserbundle. Single Sign-On system is working now, but FOSuserbundle login form is not working.

This is my security.yml

```
security:

encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface:
      id: app.my_password_encoder

    PDias\SamlBundle\Security\User\SamlUser: plaintext


role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:

    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    backend_samlservice:
        id: saml.backend.fosuser.provider

firewalls:

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle

            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            require_previous_session: true
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            default_target_path: /
            use_forward: true
            use_referer: false

        saml:
            provider: backend_samlservice
            direct_entry: false
            login_path: /login-saml
            check_path: /login-check-saml
            default_target_path: /
            always_use_default_target_path: true
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /login
        anonymous: true

    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

        remember_me:
            key:      '%secret%'
            lifetime: 604800 # 1 week
            path:     /
            domain: ~

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/sendemail, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^, role: ROLE_USER }


acl:
    connection: default
```

Even if I was not using Single Sign-On, backend_samlservice will be executed. 
When I use ID & Password to login to the website, I will be redirected to the login page.

Do I have to add something?

Thanks for your anwsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this problem.

The point was SimpleSAML_Session. I had to clean up the session like this.

https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp#section_6

```
$session = SimpleSAML_Session::getSessionFromRequest();
$session->cleanup();
```

I added this code on the SamlAuth.php(pdias/saml-bundle/PDias/SamlBundle/Saml). Then it started working.